# Automapper: map hierarchy entity

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the Entity model with User field and Parent (the same type).

```
class User {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
class Entity {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public virtual User user { get;set; }
    public virtual Entity Parent {get; set;}
}

class UserModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class EntityModel {
    public UserModel { get;set; }
    public EntityParentModel { get; set; }
}

class EntityParentModel {
    public UserModel { get;set; }
}
```

I tried to map Entity to EntityModel using AutoMapper, but get the following error:

> The type 'UserModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

So, anybody has idea what I need to do? I could provide mapping configuration, if it is needed.

UP: Project function is simple:

```
private static readonly Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, string[], IQueryable<TModel>> ProjectFunction = (query, expand) => query.Project().To<TModel>(membersToExpand: expand);
```

Configuration is here:

```
CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
CreateMap<Entity, EntityModel>();
CreateMap<Entity, EntityParentModel>();
```

Comment: Mapping configuration is needed, yes. And ideally you also would include your mapping code, Project() to etc

Comment: Hi, Jimmy. I added ProjectFunciton and Configuration. I hope it would be usefull

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with EF, is this a TPH kind of EF config? I don't think you'll need the Entity/EntityModel configs in AutoMapper, just the concrete types.